# Xcode 7.2 ios 9.2, App installation failed, could not inspect the application package

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, xcode7

[image]

I cant figure out this problem and I have been trying to follow others solution.

1) I dont have any latin characters in my name

2) Cleared Derived Data

3) Clean Build.

4) There are no errors in my device log or even in the console.

It works fine in the simulator
Any idea how to fix this